# training unbalanced data in libsvm

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, machine-learning, libsvm

I have 25 classes and class 0 included all the the negative samples of all 24 other classes so the number of samples in this class is much more bigger than the others (e.g 10 times bigger because it should include all of the negative samples from the 24 other classes)

Now my question is what should I do when I want to train this data set ?

Do I **have to** use unbalaced training option which libsvm prodives ? -w0 1 -w1 ....

I mean is it **obligatory** to use this option or not ?

because When I'm training the data **without this option** it gives 99.8% accuracy for separating classes and when I'm testing this accurate  model !!! for some classes I get 100% accuracy and for some other classes I get 0.0%  !!!

I mean for some classes it will not miss any sample but for another class it will always return 0 !!! which means it is a negative sample !!!

I want to use this option but I dont know the rules for it. I mean How should I set a value for a class using this option?

Suppose number of samples in each classes are :

class 0 -> 3433

class 1 -> 745

class 2 -> 232

class 3 -> 53

.
.
.
class 23 -> 975

how should I set wi for each class should I scaled them between [0,1] or [-1 1] or (-inf +inf) or what ?

Summary  >

1). is it obligatory to use -wi option for my dataset ?

2). how should I set this value

Thanks

Comment: So if if you check and say sample 3 is not in class 1, do you put it in class 0, even if it is an example of class 2?  In other words, do any samples show up in more than one class?

Comment: of course not ,it might happen that two samples from two classes be similar in 60% of feature vector value but it will never happen that a sample from a specific class appears in another one ...

Comment: I see, I was just making sure that wasn't the reason for the huge class 0 sample size.   The weights are 1 by default and you may have to try some different values with a validation set.   Unfortunately, the w parameter modifies C on a per-class basis which is also going to affect regularization/smoothness of the decision boundary in the low dimensional space.  You could leave the other classes at 1 for now and start decreasing w for class 0.  You need to use the -wi option if class 0 isn't really as common as it is in the training data. Otherwise you aren't really achieving 99.8% accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not obligatory, it depends on your data. if your classes are easy to separate there is no need. start without weight and have a look at the [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). if your errors are between a crowded class and a sparse class some tweaking on the weight may help.

Comment: although I got my answer some months ago ... but yes that's true ... it is not obligatory and it all depends on the data in the nth dimension space ...

Answer (score 0):

Not able to comment so I'll write it as an answer:

Two suggestions:

1. decrease the weight for class0
2. or adopt a 2-step approach:

   - combine all examples from other 24 classes, treat them as one class,
     and build a binary classifier
   - build a 24-way classifier only for the positive examples. use it if the classification result from last step is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have +ve and -ve data for each class, you should train 24 binary classifiers.
Then when you put in a test case, if there is more than one SVM that has a positive prediction, pick the class for which the classifier has the highest output probability.

If you set up a multiclass SVM with LIBSVM, internally it just trains multiple binary SVM anyway. So there is nothing odd about explicitly setting up 24 SVMs yourself.

Comment: i strongly disagree to set up binary classifiers only and implement voting on your own. there is very little chance that you can implement a better voter. the class with highest probability against "0" does not necessarily win against other non-"0" classes (Rock-paper-scissors problem). leave this to the educated mathematicians who provided the theories behind the implementation.